# "I would live in New York" or "I used to live in New York"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, modal-verbs

Ok, [This site](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/would) says

> We use would to refer to typical habitual actions and events in the
>   past. This is usually a formal use and it often occurs in stories
>   (narratives):
>
> I had a friend from Albany, which is about 36 miles away, and we would
>   meet every Thursday morning and she would help us.
>
> Then he would wash; then he would eat his toast; then he would read
>   his paper by the bright burning fire of electric coals.

However, it also says:

> We can’t use would in this way **to talk about states**. In these cases,
>   we say used to instead of would:
>
> I used to live in Melbourne when I was a kid.
>
> Not: I would live in Melbourne when I was a kid.

So, what does "**to talk about states**" mean?

Comment: When they say "talk about states" I think they mean *states of being*, and I think you may be confusing that with "states" as in "geographical divisions".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, a state is a sitution that exists without change for a period of time. If you live in New York, that's a state. If you visit New York regularly, that's not a state: it's a series of separate events which you could describe as a habitual action.

> I used to live in New York - *state*
>   I used to visit New York regularly - *habitual action*
>   I would visit New York regularly - *habitual action*

As you can see, **used to** can be used about both states and habitual actions, but **would** can only be used about habitual actions.